# Correct sentence for starting a work after two hours from now

Tags: future-time

I want to say I will start a project after two hours from now. What is the correct sentence for it?

- I'll start within two hours
- I'll start after two hours
- I'll start in two hours
- Or...?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Hamid. We expect people to do some research before asking a question: in this case, you could look up to the words within, after and in in a good dictionary, like this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/within If you are still unsure, please edit your question to include details of your research, with links, and explain what exactly you still don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll start in two hours.

Or if you want to be very precise

> I will start the project two hours from now.

It is slightly odd to want to say "exactly two hours from now".  Normally you want to say "two hours or less", meaning "I'll start soon."  or "I won't start for two hours. (I busy for two hours) but I'll start soon after that.

If you are working to a timetable and will start in exactly two hours you'd say

> I'll start at 2:20.

Using absolute, not relative time.